# HTML5 unterminated attribute quote error recovery

Tags: html, error-handling

I've read a lot about the HTML5 spec and how it specifies error recovery behavior for implementations.

I'm trying to find where it specifies how a user agent should handle unterminated quotes in HTML attributes, like:

```
<div class = "foo>blah blah</div>
```

In the **[error recovery portion](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#an-introduction-to-error-handling-and-strange-cases-in-the-parser)** of the spec, it discusses handling mismatched tags and unclosed formatting tags, but doesn't seem to address unterminated quotes.  Is there a standardized way that HTML5 is supposed to handle unterminated quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [HTML5 serialized as XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-xhtml-syntax.html#the-xhtml-syntax), i.e. using XML syntax, no error recovery is made, for errors like this. The Draconian laws of [XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) apply. Technically, the browser is only required to report an error, but in XML traditions, this means that *only* the first well-formedness error is reported and no document is shown (though some browsers nowadays try show the start of the document up to that error). – In this case, the first well-formedness error is a “<” character in an attribute value.

In HTML5 serialized as HTML, the rules in section 8, The HTML syntax, apply. In this case, the relevanr item is 8.2.4.38 [Attribute value (double-quoted) state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-value-%28double-quoted%29-state). It says that characters are scanned and collected in the attribute value until a quotation mark or end of data is encountered. This is what actually happens in modern browsers. In the given case, if it happens that there is no quotation mark later in the document, all the rest will be taken as the `class` attribute value. If there is a quotation mark, it will be taken as terminating the attribute value. This in turn tends to cause an out-of-synch situation, since that quotation mark was probably mean to be an *opening* quote for something.

So it’s not particularly useful error recovery, but it’s what the HTML5 CR says. It would often be more useful to treat end of line as terminating an attribute value, but this can’t be done, since HTML5 allows line breaks in attribute values on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a standardized way in which a browser is supposed to handle unterminated quotes but what I have found is that most major browsers do not make any real attempt to handle unterminated quotes and they will often cause problems outside of the element you didn't terminate the quotes in. So definitely avoid unterminated quotes and do not rely on error recovery to terminate them for you as it won't terminate properly and cause problems.